# LaTeX change name of \bibliography{} heading (or remove entirely)

Tags: latex

I have seen this question asked a few times on here but none of the answers have gotten me exactly what I want. I am using Overleaf to write a LaTeX document and when I make a bibliography (using the natbib library) it automatically makes a heading named "References". Can I remove this heading somehow? I've tried a couple other options but they haven't worked. I've attached a minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here is a citation \citep{Source}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what didn't work with the existing responses - perhaps you could point to them and indicate what you didn't like about the results? Does replacing the `\bibliography{refs}` with the following help? (BTW, as this is not an Overleaf question, it's just LaTeX, perhaps remove the `overleaf` tag and reference.)

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand
\refname{}
\bibliography{refs}
\endgroup
```

Comment: this works, sorry for the lack of detail! The mistake I had made is that I didn't use \begingroup and \endgroup, only the \renewcommand\refname{} portion, which did not work. apologies and appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks @PeterThompson - if you think the answer is correct or helpful, please consider accepting it :)